# Collapse using Transition Vue

Tags: laravel-5, vue.js, transition

I would like to use Vue's collapse in my code, but I have an error.

```
[Vue warn]: <transition-group> children must be keyed: <p>
```

My component:

```
<template xmlns:v-model="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:v-on="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <section style="background-color: #dedede;">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="Consult-faq container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>Cursos</h2>
            <a v-for="(course,id) in courses" v-on:click="course.show = !course.show">
              <a v-on:click="show = !show">
                <div class="col-xs-12" style="border-bottom: solid;border-bottom-color: #999999;border-bottom-width:1px ">
                  <div class="col-xs-12">
                    <h4>
                      <i v-if="course.show" class="fa fa-plus-square text-right" aria-hidden="true"/>
                      <i v-else class="fa fa-minus-square text-right" aria-hidden="true"/>
                      {{course.text}}
                    </h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <transition-group name="fade">
                  <p v-if="show">
                    <div class="col-xs-12">
                      <article v-for="n in 2" class="Module-content">
                        <div class=" col-sm-12 col-md-6" style="position: relative;">
                          <div v-for="(course, index) in course.courses">
                            <course-card v-if="index % 2 == n - 1" :course="course"></course-card>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </article>
                    </div>
                  </p>
                </transition-group>
              </a>
            </a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>
<script>
  export default{
    props : [
      'courses'
    ],
    data(){
      return {
          show: false 
      }
    },
    mounted() {
      console.log(this.courses)  
    }
  }
</script>
```

So, I'd like to know to collapse item per item. Like this in image.

[image]

When I click to expand, all courses expand or  close all courses close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using vue-resource, I was using Guzzle in Laravel and require data in Controller make this not reactive. And I solved this problem using vue-resource in component.

Answer (score 1):

Transition is irrelevant here (though you can get rid of that warning by using `transition` instead of `transition-group`, because the transition is only acting on a single node, not a group.)

Right now you're depending on a single variable `show` to control all of the elements' visibility, so they will all respond to clicks on any of them:

```
<a v-on:click="show = !show">
<p v-if="show" >
```

You need individual variables for each element if you want them to expand/collapse separately.  You partially did this already, just change the remaining instances of `show` with `course.show` and you should be good to go.

(Probably want to clean up that nested `<a>` within `<a>` while you're at it; you can just remove the inner one.)

Comment: Ok, I refactor this, but the error persists. 

`[Vue warn]: <transition-group> children must be keyed: <p> `

Comment: I added that to the answer (you want transition instead of transition-group here.)  The transition warning is not relevant to the `show` bug.